# Want to use tailwind default classes in chrome extension but rem takes the size from current webpage html tag instead of my shadow root html font size

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, tailwind-css, shadow-dom

I am building my chrome extension and I am using **`vue` and `tailwind css`**. I am using **shadow root element** to render my extension's html on any page. Tailwind css uses `rem` as units in their rendered css in spacing, margin, padding etc,.

For e.g. If I use class `pt-8` it renders in css as `padding-top: 2rem` now If I am on stackoverflow page it becomes `26px` because, the stackoverflow site has `13px` as its html tag font size so in that page `1rem` becomes `13px` but If I go to another pages like tailwind doc it has font size `16px` in its html tag or maybe browser has by default `16px` font size, so the `2rem` becomes `32px`.

So now if I use default classes of tailwind the sizing and spacing of my chrome extension's elements changes according to webpage I am on, I have thought it will stay consistent if I give font size to my shadow root html tag, but whatever size I give to my shadow root html tag but `rem` takes the size according to current webpage instead of my shadow root elements font size, you can see the shadow root element in attached image and in its css, it has font size of `16px`.

[image: chrome extension shadow root html image]

I have tried to change font size of `html` tag of root element of my chrome extension but it is not helping,

I have tried to find on stackoverflow but the answerer were saying the same thing to change shadow root html element's font size but whatever I do it keep taking `rem` size based on the current webpage's html element's font size.

I have also look into extending tailwind config and set all of the units to `px` instead of `rem`, currently only that is the solution but I think `rem` should also work, why it is not working is the question, does anyone know any solution or know why its not working?

Comment: This is the intended behavior per the CSS specification. You'll have to put your content inside an iframe. It can be a `web_accessible_resources` iframe.